# Poisson equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

[image]

For the equation $\frac{f(x+he_i-y)-f(x-y)}{h}$, I am wondering whether we should treat $y$ is constant here?

Comment: For similar questions, see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1953478/792125 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/468558/792125.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My interpretation is that you are unsure what
$$\frac{f(x+he_i-y)-f(x-y)}{h}\to f_{x_i}(x-y)$$
is supposed to mean (please comment if this is wrong!)

In this expression, we are treating *both* $x$ and $y$ as constant, while sending the $h$ to $0$. More formally the line could be written out as

$$\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+he_i-y)-f(x-y)}{h}= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x-y),$$
i.e. the expression goes to the directional derivative of $f$ evaluated at the point $(x-y)$. This is true because the left hand side is in fact the limit definition of the derivative.

Comment: Thank you!!! It solves my confustion.